# How to use OCR module in a pdftron node js app?

Tags: ocr, pdftron

I want to use OCR module in my node app, but I don't see full documentation on that. There are some code snippets available for the functionality but I am not sure how to add the module in a node app (I didn't find any npm packages for the OCR module). I am using the `@pdftron/pdfnet-node` in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will first need to download the OCR module from the [PDFTron website.](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/linux/download/linux/)

Once you have downloaded and extracted the module to a directory where your program can access it, you will need to call the `addResourceSearchPath()` method to pass the location of the module to the SDK.

Please see the [OCR sample here](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/node/js/OCRTest?platforms=nodejs) for reference.